# is it better to take minimum measure of all measures or the mean of minimum measures as a minimum measure

Tags: climate-change, evaporation

We have taken the measurments of temperature, humidity, net radiation and pressure in our lab so we can calculate the potential reference EvapoTranspiration. So to find out the potential reference ET we have the minimum temperature and maximum temperature of each half an hour. same for humidity. My question is to find out ET per day, should I take the mean of minimums or the minimum of all? I have the same question for maximums. per day and per month.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a subject expert, so can't answer, but I wanted to comment in admiration of the title. It's either wonderful or horrific, or possibly both. You may like to search Youtube for the speeches of Sir Humphry Abbleby :-)

Comment: Funny. I'll try for a simpler title..

Comment: In relation to what? What do you mean by "better?" If you want the daily maximum (or mean or minimum) ET, you need to calculate it for the entire day, and apply your desired statistical function.

Comment: Simce this is mostly a statistics question, it might help if you provide the formula you're plugging the minimum and maximum temperatures into.  Are daily / seasonal cycles being represented?